# Accessing to a state after a fetch to displayed it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, this, state

I would like to display some fetched information stocked into a state with react.

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { price: [] };
  }

  fetchResult = () => {
    fetch('https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=BTC,ETH&tsyms=USD,EUR', {
    })
      .then(response => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(price => {
        this.setState({ price: price })
        console.log("TCL: price", price);
        console.log("TCL: this.state.price.BTC.USD", this.state.price.BTC.USD)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);       
      });
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.fetchResult()
    setInterval(this.fetchResult, 30000000)
  }  

render() {

    return (

         <div className="overviewcard">

            <p>{this.state.price}</p>
            <p>{this.state.price.BTC.USD}</p>

         </div>

    );
  }

// Console.log(price) = {"BTC":{"USD":10208.24,"EUR":9228.96},"ETH":{"USD":213.4,"EUR":192.97}}  
// Console.log(this.state.price.BTC.USD) = 10208.24
```

So when I'm trying to display it with :

`{this.state.price.BTC.USD}`

I get this  error:

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'USD' of undefined"

`{this.state.price}`

I get this error:

> "Objects are not valid as a React child"

I read other topics and i did not find any solutions, i tried to bind "this" and put function arrow. I don't know what to do about it.

Thanks for your help

Comment: For starters, you are initializing `price` to be an array in your constructor, so I would change that to an object to match. then check for the key you want before rendering it. `{this.state.price.BTC && this.state.price.BTC.USD}`

Comment: it doesn't change anything, i have the two same errors by initializing `price` as an `array` or an `object`

Answer (score 2):

A few issues with your code:

1. You set `price` as an empty array on initial state, but then try to access it as object. Change your initial state to `this.state = { price: {} };`
2. `setState` is async, so logging it to console straight after setting will show the old value, you need to use the callback to `setState`:

```
this.setState({ price: price } , () => {
  console.log("state:", this.state);
})
```

3. You're trying to render `this.state.price`, but it's supposed to be an object, so that's why you get an error.
4. Do not use `setInterval` in `componentDidMount` as it will repeatedly call your api fetch method with the same url.
5. You're trying to render `this.state.price.BTC.USD`, however before the data has been fetched and set to the state, the price value on state doesn't have any props, and you'll get `cannot access property 'BTC' of undefined` error. In this case a better idea is to delay the render until the data is fetched. You can do it by showing a loader meanwhile. Additionally, it's a good idea to have some error handling, where you'd display an error message if the data fetching wasn't successful:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      price: {},
      error: false, // Track error state
      loading: true // set loading to true in the beginning
    };
  }

  fetchResult = () => {
    this.setState({ error: false });
    fetch(
      "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=BTC,ETH&tsyms=USD,EUR",
      {}
    )
      .then(response => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(price => {
        this.setState(
          {
            price: price,
            loading: false // Disable loading after data is fetched
          },
          () => {
            console.log("state:", this.state);
          }
        );
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
        this.setState({ error: true, loading: false });  // Also disable loading in case of error
      });
  };

  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.fetchResult();
  };

  render() {
    if (this.state.error) {
      return <p>Error message here</p>;
    }
    return this.state.loading ? (
      <p>Loading...</p> // Show loader before the data is ready
    ) : (
      <div className="overviewcard">
        <p>{this.state.price.BTC.USD}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

I have recently wrote a [post](https://claritydev.net/blog/the-most-common-mistakes-when-using-react) about the most common mistakes with React, which you may find useful.

Also here's a [working sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-g2lxg).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, but i have the same errors `TypeError: Cannot read property 'USD' of undefined` Or `Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

Comment: First of all, remove `this.state.price` from the render and second check that your api actually returns the data in format that you're trying to render.

Comment: Yes the fetch is working great, i'm console logging :
 `this.state.price` who return `{"BTC":{"USD":10206.65,"EUR":9222.6},"ETH":{"USD":213.91,"EUR":193.22}}`
`this.state.price.BTC.USD`who return the `number` 10206.65

Comment: I have added a link to working codesandbox, so I'm not sure what did you copy wrong there, but the code in the answer works.